# How can I treat an asynchronous iterator like a sync iterator?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

The comprehension notation supports generating lists from asynchronous iterators.
How can I do this in a custom list class?

Of course, you can use `list.append` to generate the list, but I would like to know the smart way.

```py
import asyncio


class MyList(list):
    pass


async def iterate():
    yield 1
    yield 2


async def main():
    return [x async for x in iterate()]
    # return MyList(x async for x in iterate()) # NG
    # return MyList([x async for x in iterate()])  # OK However, there is a lot of waste because the list is generated twice

result = asyncio.run(main())
print(result) # [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python magic methods aren't async - for example, in your `main()` you never `await` the `MyList` constructor, so it can't be async either. The normal way would be to provide a method such as `extend_async` and use it:

```
class MyList(list):
    async def extend_async(self, aiter):
        async for obj in aiter:
            self.append(obj)

async def main():
     lst = MyList()
     await lst.extend_async(x async for x in iterate())
     return lst
```

Or, if you want to make `main` shorter, you can create a helper:

```
class MyList(list):
    @staticmethod
    async def from_aiter(aiter):
        self = MyList()
        async for obj in aiter:
            self.append(obj)
        return self

async def main():
     return await MyList.from_aiter(x async for x in iterate())
```

And finally, having said all that... if you *really* insist on async construction, you *could* hack it using a metaclass:

```
class Hack(type):
    async def __call__(cls, aiter):
        self = type.__call__(cls)
        await self.extend_async(aiter)
        return self

class MyList(list, metaclass=Hack):
    async def extend_async(self, aiter):
        async for obj in aiter:
            self.append(obj)

async def main():
     return await MyList(x async for x in iterate())
```

But this latter code is meant only as a learning exercise, don't try using it in production.